# Backward compatible `add_compile_definitions`

Tags: cmake

I am working on fixing some CMake files that have been made with a version newer than 3.10, but should have been coded to be compatible with 3.10.

There is a particular line:

```
add_compile_definitions(SOME_BOOL_VARIABLE)
```

that I can not figure out how to change to make it work with version 3.10. The `add_definitions(SOME_BOOL_VARIABLE)` command was the obvious thing that I tried, but produces errors with "no such file of directory".

Comment: `add_definitions(-DSOME_BOOL_VARIABLE)`. Exactly such example is written in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/add_definitions.html) for that command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the CMake documentation, the functionality of [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_definitions.html) and [`add_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_compile_definitions.html) is essentially the identical:

> Adds preprocessor definitions to the compiler command line for targets in the current directory and below (whether added before or after this command is invoked).

The difference is in the syntax accepted for the command arguments. The older `add_definitions()` command requires the `-D` flag be prepended to each definition.

```
add_definitions(-DSOME_BOOL_VARIABLE)
```

The newer `add_compile_definitions()` command (available in CMake 3.12 and above) is cleaner, and does not require the `-D` flag prefix.

---

If you are refactoring your code, modern CMake encourages a target-centric approach. Whenever possible, you should prefer the [`target_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) command to add preprocessor definitions to *only* those targets that require them.

```
target_compile_definitions(MyLibraryTarget PRIVATE SOME_BOOL_VARIABLE)
```